# Generalizing the functions of a key/value database for both on disk (IO) and pure cases?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The basic functions of a key value database are *store*, *fetch*, and *delete*. I'm attempting to write a typeclass that allows for the return types of these functions to be either pure or in `IO` so that I can write a single engine that works for both an in-memory `Data.Map` backed implementation and an on-disk implementation.

The *pure* typeclass might look something like this:

```
class PureQueryable d where
  fetch  :: d -> Key -> Maybe Value
  insert :: d -> Key -> Value -> d
  delete :: d -> Key -> Maybe d
```

...whereas the `IO` typeclass might look something like this:

```
class IOQueryable d
  fetch  :: d -> Key -> IO (Maybe Value)
  insert :: d -> Key -> Value -> IO d
  delete :: d -> Key -> IO (Maybe d)
```

I'm attempting to combine these two, and as suggested by someone (Vektorweg1) on `#haskell` I wrote this:

```
class Queryable d r where
  fetch  :: d -> Key -> ??? 
  insert :: d -> Key -> Value -> ??? 
  delete :: d -> Key -> ???
```

I am unsure of what to write in place of the `???` to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a class for this at all? This isn't the sort of problem classes are good for in Haskell.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: My first question would be: what do you get out of this? For an abstraction to make sense, you need to be able to productively write code that's agnostic to which implementation you're using. What productive code can you write that works across any implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Like Carl, I have my doubts about the utility of this as well, but here goes nothing (note that I'm typing on my phone, so the syntax for the associated types may be completely wrong):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Queryable (d :: * -> *) where
  type Key
  type M
  fetch :: d v -> Key -> M v
  insert :: d v -> Key -> v -> M v
  delete :: d v -> Key -> M ()
```

Now you can instantiate the class using any functor:

```
instance Queryable IOIntDict where
  type Key IOIntDict = Int
  type M = IO
  ...
```

For pure stuff, you use `Data.Functor.Identity` as your functor, or maybe just use the identity type family (I'm not sure what approach would actually work out better).

Comment: What would you use instead of a typeclass?

Comment: @broma0, as Carl said, the real question is "What are you actually trying to do?" Can you imagine some problems you might want to solve, and then explain how a common interface of the flavor you envision will help you share code between them? If so, you can edit your question with the gory details.

Comment: The problem I want to solve is having a db engine that works with both IO and pure backends. I figured that this would best be accomplished with a typeclass

Comment: @broma0, you still haven't explained why you want that. How would you use it? Can you write a toy program to explain?

Comment: Imagine a key value db composed of many "buckets", each of which act as a unique mapping of keys to values. It would be nice to be able to use a memory backend (pure, using state monad) for one bucket but an on disk (IO) backend for another. Since I'd like my engine, the code that handles the storage and indexing for the db, to be as concise and polymorphic as possible, I need some way to abstract the "backend" for each bucket. If this explanation still isn't sufficient I will add some more code to my question.

Comment: @broma0, it still is not. Please add to your question.